# How to suppress controls of a related model on django admin

Tags: django

I have two related models on django 2.2.4. I only want to allow one model to be editable, for the other it is only allowed to be related to the first one.

The model that is not editable is a State model. Must never change.
The second model is a User model. Must use the State model as a field related only.

Here is the code:

```py
class State(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class User(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
```

So there are two questions:

1) I would like to hide the State model from the admin, avoiding that any data could be changed. Is that possible?

2) In the User model in the admin, in the screen to insert a User, there are shortcuts to edit the State model. Is there a way to get rid of these controls?

Comment: Usually only an administrator has access to the admin-site, so I do not really understand why you want to prevent that. Even if you do that, a database administrator can usually change the values in the database with SQL queries.

Comment: I would like to prevent the admin from messing the data on the auxiliar tables... but thank you for your answer.

Comment: If you do not want State data changed (point 1) why do you want to edit it (point 2)?

Comment: I do not want to edit State data. I only want to be shown in the related model. But I see your point HenryM, my mistake. I had just to not register the model in the admin.py!